# Telerik Report displays only first value from Dataset on every report page

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I am working on Telerik Reports. I have main report that displays the customer basic information. In addition to basic information, the customerID is passed to a function `GenerationBubbleSheet(ds.tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].toString())` that displays the customerID in Bubble Format(by setting the Visibility of bubbles on/off)

If I loop through the Dataset like 
`for(int i = 0; i < ds.tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
   GenerationBubbleSheet(ds.tables[0].Rows[i]["CustomerID"].toString());
}`
It displays all customerID's on one re[ort page instead of showing one customerID per page.

It works fine when only one customer exists but in case of more than one customer dataset e.g 10 entries, it displays only first customerID on every customer Report(other information displys correctly. How can I resolve this?